# wordpress change server to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem:

When I type `<a href="http://localhost/myblog">localhost/myblog</a>` I get redirected to the live site on production server.(I have made the changes in the wordpress)

When I type `<a href="http://localhost/myblog/wp-admin">localhost/myblog/wp-admin</a>`, it goes correctly to the local site's admin interface.

Again from the admin interface, I can't navigate to the local site cause it takes me to the production site.

Strange behaviour.

The changes I made:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://localhost/myblog' WHERE option_value = 'http://www.example.com';
```

The permalink settings are as follows(does that matter?)

```
<a href="http://localhost/myblog/?p=123">localhost/myblog/?p=123</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the admin section, general settings, did you update the URL there?

The two in question would be

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

Comment: Thats unusual, as normally it uses that to present you the URLs from within the site